# Finding a median of 2 arrays of the same size - the O(log n) algorithm doesn't yield a correct result

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

I'm trying to solve the problem of calculating median of merged two sorted arrays of the same size, with distinct elements.

Source of algorithm: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/
This algorithm is used in several sources over the internet as the O(log n) solution. However I don't think it works for the example I made up.

My counter-example:

We have 2 sorted arrays with no duplicates:

`[2,3,12,14]` & `[1,5,8,9]`

Merged sorted array is: `a = [1,2,3,5,8,9,12,14]` Median: `13/2 = 6.5`

Following the algorithm:

Median of `[2,3,12,14]` is `(3+12)/2= 7.5 = m1`

Median of `[1,5,8,9]` is `(5+8)/2 = 6.5 = m2`

We see `m1>m2`. So following the algorithm, we consider the first half of first array, and second half of second array. We have `a1 = [2,3]` and `a2 = [8,9]`.

Now we reached a base case and we have a result of `(max(a1[0],a2[0]) + min(a1[1],a2[1]))/2 = 8+3=11/2=5.5` which is clearly not `6.5`.

This is the only algorithm I see that has O(log n) solution but it seems flawed. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Well, in the description of the algorithm, it says "From first element of ar1 to m1 (ar1[0...|_n/2_|]) ... From m2 to last element of ar2  (ar2[|_n/2_|...n-1]". Maybe you have to include all the elements used to generate the median (in the even case): [2,3,12,14] , [1,5,8,9] -> [2,3,12], [5,8,9] -> [3,12], [5,8] -> 6.5

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you I think that might be the problem indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always give the same result of the first method, the second one must end up with the same numbers in the final iteration.

For instance, the example provided should lead to 6.5

[2, 3, 12, 14], [1, 5, 8, 9] → [1, 2, 3, **5**, **8**, 9, 12, 14] → (5 + 8)/2 → 6.5

To ensure that, when dividing ranges with even number of elements, you must add the element below are beyond the middle:

[2, **3**, **12**, 14], [1, **5**, **8**, 9] → [2, **3**, **12**], [**5**, **8**, 9] → [3, 12], [5, 8] → 6.5

As a matter of fact, the relevant part of the code in the page you linked is this

```
int getMedian(int ar1[],  
              int ar2[], int n)
{
    // ...
    if (m1 < m2) 
    { 
        if (n % 2 == 0) 
            return getMedian(ar1 + n / 2 - 1,    // <- Note the difference
                             ar2, n - n / 2 + 1); 
        return getMedian(ar1 + n / 2,            // <-
                         ar2, n - n / 2); 
    } 

    if (n % 2 == 0) 
        return getMedian(ar2 + n / 2 - 1,        // The same here
                         ar1, n - n / 2 + 1); 
    return getMedian(ar2 + n / 2,  
                     ar1, n - n / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't trace by hand, run the code.

The Python versions of both algorithms produce the correct answer for your attempted counter-example.

I cannot promise that all implementations work correctly.  But remember that it is always much more likely that you made a mistake than that something that has been reviewed by many is wrong.  (Not always wrong, which is why I ran actual code on your example.) And the odds of error go up by a lot when you try to trace code by hand.

Comment: Re: "it is always much more likely that you made a mistake than that something that has been reviewed by many is wrong": True, but in this case I think the OP is quite right. (You mention the Python implementation, but the OP is asking about the algorithm description, which is where the mistake is.)